# How can I tell what host a packet comes from using netcat?

Tags: bash, udp, netcat

I'm trying to write a server using netcat and bash. to recieve asynchronous packets, i'm using the command 
`netcat -lu 6791`

How can I tell what host a packet came from? Is there a better tool i should be using then netcat (socat maybe?)

Comment: (2 upvoters as mad as you are?! :p).  I don't think this is practical in bash.  socat would let you restrict access to a range of addresses using the "range" option, if that helps.  (And the "tcpwrap" option does something similar, but slightly more powerful).

Comment: `netcat -vv -lu -p 6791` should report source and destination for each packet received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@twalberg's suggestion, 
`netcat -vv -lu -p 6791` worked.

Answer (score 0):

`wireshark` (GUI tool), `tshark` (text-based version of `wireshark`), and/or `tcpdump` (very similar to `tshark`, at least until you start messing with filtering out specific packets or searching for certain patterns or anything more complex) come immediately to mind...

Comment: Inspecting packets on the wire is nor very convenient. Presumably you would want to be able to communicate the remote IP to your server process somehow.